# Failed to update TargetChangeListener

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing problem when creating new xml file in
eclipse,
it shows

failed to update TargetChangedListener

Egit couldn't detect the installation path "getPrefix" of native git. Hence EGit can't respect system level..

Thanking you...